# Detecting email address of the owner of an appointment in a delegate calendar

Tags: outlook-redemption

Is it possible to always find the email address owner of an appointment in a delegate calendar in Outlook? I can detect if an appointment does not belong to a the main users folder and then, in some cases (and i cant work out exactly which) i can get the email adress of the delegate user from position 120 in the folder storeId. But in other cases this contains the email address of the main outlook user.
I can see, using OutlookSpy, that IMAPISession contains a list of added calendars and, from there, PR_EMS_AB_PUBLIC_DELEGATES_BL_O contains the email address of the delegate user but I  dont know if this is useful as I need to get, from an open appointment, the email address of the calendar the appointment belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast `RDOMail.Parent` property to `RDOFolder`, then use `RDOFolder.Store` to check if it is `RDOExchangeMailBoxStore`. In that case, use `RDOExchangeMailBoxStore.Owner.SMTPAddress`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, Your suggestion seems to work very nicely on my test machine but im still not getting the delegate email address on other machines. And the only difference i can see is different verions of outlook. The version it works on is Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20172) 64-bit. The version it doesnt work on is Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2204 Build 16.0.15128.20240) 64-bit

Comment: Are you getting the primary mailbox owner address? Was the delegate mailbox added as a separate store (Exchange account settings | More Settings | Advanced | Mailboxes) or only the Calendar folder?

Comment: Just the calendar.

Comment: And this is how im getting the email address (which, of course, could be incorrect):                     RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.Logon("", "", false, false, null, false);
                   session.MAPIOBJECT = CurrentSession.MAPIOBJECT;                  object RDOAppt = session.GetMessageFromID(olAppointment.EntryID);

                    RDOAppointmentItem RDOApptItem = (RDOAppointmentItem)RDOAppt;
                    string email = ((RDOExchangeMailboxStore)((RDOFolder)RDOApptItem.Parent).Store).Owner.SMTPAddress;

Comment: There is no reason to call RDOSession.Logon since you are setting the RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property anyway.

Comment: If it is just the Calendar folder, keep in mind that MSEMS provider caches it in a folder stored in the primary mailbox's OST file, so the owner looks like the primary user. If I remember correctly, you can work the parent folder hierarchy (based on the RDOFolder.Parent property) that will point to a folder that has the delegate user's address.

Comment: I cant find it via the parent folder hierarchy but thats probably my lack of knowledge. I did find someone with a similar problem and he solved it by getting the delegate email address from the appointment's recipient. Of course, that wont work for a meeting as there could be multiple recipients. Although in Microsoft  365 Apps I think the delegate calendar name (which was 'calendar' in Outlook 2019) now defaults to the delegate user name and so i can use that to search the list of recipients and match on recipient name. But I think that calendar name is just a name and can be renamed.